# Test GoogleApiClient under AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, testing, google-api-client

I'm trying to test an app using [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html), but have had no luck so far. Is there anything I'm missing, or is it impossible to test GoogleApi Client under android.test?

```
public class BookTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    // to wait for a callack from Google Api
    boolean connected = false;

    public void testGoogleApiClient() {
        final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        assertNotNull(getContext());

        GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    connected = true;
                    signal.countDown();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    fail("should not reach here");
                    signal.countDown();
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    fail("should not reach here");
                    signal.countDown();
                }
            })
            .build();
        try {
            signal.await(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            fail("should not reach here");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertTrue(connected);
    }
}
```

falls into assertion failure like:

```
07-08 02:14:39.339  19179-19194/net.mootoh.messtin_android.app I/TestRunner﹕ failed: testGoogleApiClient(net.mootoh.messtin_android.test.BookTest)
07-08 02:14:39.339  19179-19194/net.mootoh.messtin_android.app I/TestRunner﹕ ----- begin exception -----
07-08 02:14:39.339  19179-19194/net.mootoh.messtin_android.app I/TestRunner﹕ junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
            at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:48)
            at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
            at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:27)
            at net.mootoh.messtin_android.test.BookTest.testGoogleApiClient(BookTest.java:58)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
            at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
            at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
            at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
            at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
            at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
            at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
            at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
            at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
            at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
07-08 02:14:39.349  19179-19194/net.mootoh.messtin_android.app I/TestRunner﹕ ----- end exception -----
07-08 02:14:39.349  19179-19194/net.mootoh.messtin_android.app I/TestRunner﹕ finished: testGoogleApiClient(net.mootoh.messtin_android.test.BookTest)
07-08 02:14:39.349  19179-19194/net.mootoh.messtin_android.app I/TestRunner﹕ started: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(net.mootoh.messtin_android.test.BookTest)
07-08 02:14:39.359  19179-19194/net.mootoh.messtin_android.app I/TestRunner﹕ finished: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(net.mootoh.messtin_android.test.BookTest)
07-08 02:14:39.359  19179-19194/net.mootoh.messtin_android.app I/TestRunner﹕ passed: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(net.mootoh.messtin_android.test.BookTest)
```

Which means it times out in connecting to Google Api, while it successfully connects to Google Api if I use the actual activity. it might not possible to connect to Google Api with test context...?

Comment: You don't connect the GoogleApiClient?  Code sanitization error?

Comment: The point is, GoogleApiClient connects without problems if used in an actual Activity but doesn't in an testing environment (AndroidTestCase.getContext())

Comment: I was just trying to narrow the problem down a bit by nabbing the low-hanging fruit.  As written I'd expect this test to fail after 15 seconds with a timeout every single time, because connect() is never called.  GoogleApiClient should be able to connect from a test runner just fine, but you might need to play with which Context you're using.  I think you want the test application's context, not the application being tested.

Comment: @mootoh, How you have done your test case? I am finding solution for GoogleAPIClient test case writing.